# What is Groovy's MetaClass used for?

Tags: groovy

What is the use of Meta-Class in Groovy and other OO programming languages?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You're probably thinking of [Groovy's MetaClass](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/MetaClass.html):

> A MetaClass within Groovy defines the
>   behaviour of any given Groovy or Java
>   class. The MetaClass interface defines
>   two parts. The client API, which is
>   defined via the extend
>   MetaObjectProtocol interface and the
>   contract with the Groovy runtime
>   system. In general the compiler and
>   Groovy runtime engine interact with
>   methods on this class whilst MetaClass
>   clients interact with the method
>   defined by the MetaObjectProtocol
>   interface

---

The Groovy MetaClass lets you assign behavior and state to Classes at runtime without editing the original source code, it's a layer above the original Class.

It's the mechanism used by Groovy to [extend the Java JDK objects](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/).

**Example:**

```
Object.class.metaClass.explode{-> println "Boom! ${delegate} Exploded!"}
"SomeString".explode();
12345.explode();
```

**Output:**

> Boom! SomeString Exploded!
>   Boom! 12345 Exploded!

For more advanced usage, read this: [MetaClasses](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:groovy.codehaus.org/JN3525-MetaClasses)

Comment: in this case how does **${delegate}**, prints **somestring** and **12345**?

Comment: the `delegate` is the object that the metaClass has been called against.  In the first case, it's a `String`, then the second case it's an `Integer`

Comment: `delegate` is an alias for `this`, because `this` has a different meaning in the context. `delegate` is the object the method is called on.

Answer (score 6):

from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaclass)

> In object-oriented programming, a
>   metaclass is a class whose instances
>   are classes. Just as an ordinary class
>   defines the behavior of certain
>   objects, a metaclass defines the
>   behavior of certain classes and their
>   instances. Not all object-oriented
>   programming languages support
>   metaclasses. Among those that do, the
>   extent to which metaclasses can
>   override any given aspect of class
>   behavior varies. Each language has its
>   own metaobject protocol, a set of
>   rules that govern how objects,
>   classes, and metaclasses interact.

and

> Support in languages and tools
>
> The following are some of the most
>   prominent programming languages that
>   support metaclasses. Common Lisp, via
>   CLOS Groovy Objective-C Python Perl,
>   via the metaclass pragma, as well as
>   Moose Ruby Smalltalk Some less
>   widespread languages that support
>   metaclasses include OpenJava, OpenC++,
>   OpenAda, CorbaScript, ObjVLisp,
>   Object-Z, MODEL-K, XOTcl, and MELDC.