# Issue overriding method using mockFor and MockDomain

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I'm trying to unit test a service and I would like to use a mock to override a method on domain object which retrieves a file from a DB.

```
    def mockElem = mockFor(DataElement, false)
    mockElem.demand.getFile(){return tempFile}

    def dataElem = mockElem.createMock()
    dataElem.orderId = "123"
    dataElem.id = tempFileName
    dataElem.dataType = "cnv"
    dataElem.dataStatus = DataStatus.TRANSFERED
    mockDomain(DataElement, [dataElem])
```

When I call a dynamic finder on the data element I want this Mock Domain to be returned with the mockFor demand functionality for getFile. An Assertion error is thrown when the MockDomain line is reached

> junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No call to 'getClass' expected
>   at this point. Still 1 call(s) to 'getFile' expected.     at
>   groovy.mock.interceptor.StrictExpectation.match(StrictExpectation.groovy:56)
>     at grails.test.GrailsMock.createMock_closure1(GrailsMock.groovy:136)
>     at
>   grails.test.MockUtils.updateMetaClassForClass_closure95(MockUtils.groovy:1297)
>     at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)   at
>   groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:425)    at
>   grails.test.MockUtils.updateMetaClassForClass(MockUtils.groovy:1294)
>     at grails.test.MockUtils.mockDomain(MockUtils.groovy:470)   at
>   grails.plugin.spock.UnitSpec.mockDomain(UnitSpec.groovy:141)  at
>   com.genospace.inbound.pg.HemeCNVPipelineTestSpec.test processing Heme
>   file(HemeCNVPipelineTestSpec.groovy:66)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is the question.

You got this error because you are mocking an object twice :

- with `mockFor`/`createMock`
- with `mockDomain`

`mockDomain` need to know some information about objects being passedas arguments (here it verifies the class is correct) but `mockFor` did not allow that `getClass()` was called : you did not add a `demand` for such call.

Do you really need to mock with `demand` ?

I think the simple case should work :

```
def dataElem = new DataElement()
dataElem.orderId = "123"
dataElem.id = tempFileName
dataElem.dataType = "cnv"
dataElem.dataStatus = DataStatus.TRANSFERED

dataElem.file = tempFile
mockDomain(DataElement, [dataElem])
```

Comment: I want to override the functionality of the getFile on the domain object for the purposes of the test. Simply setting the file wouldn't achieve this.

Comment: So, I guess you must override the `getFile()` method by `metaclass` instead of `mockFor`. See : <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340189/what-is-groovys-metaclass-used-for>

Comment: Yes thats how I have gotten around the issue for now, but I'm told that this alters the class definition JVM wide so if other would be affected. I was hoping there would be away to achieve the isolation of the change using MockFor

Comment: You should do that in `setUp` and put back original value in `tearDown`