# Apply closure as a class method

Tags: groovy, closures

Suppose there is a function `def f = { x -> x + 4 }`.

Is there a way to call it somehow like `7.f()` and get `11`?

Comment: `def f = { x -> x + 4 }` *is* a closure

Comment: The title is grossly misleading. This post asking how to "add a method to a number", and has nothing to do with calling a function ("as a closure"?). Consider `f(7)` in context of the title and expected result.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5340218/2864740

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can add that function as a method to the Integer class, but, instead of using the `x` variable, you are better using the `delegate` of the closure:

```
Integer.metaClass.f = { delegate + 4 }

assert 7.f() == 11
```