# SOAPUI context variables - How does Groovy make this possible?

Tags: groovy, soapui

Sorry to all you Groovy dudes if this is a bit of a noob question.

In SOAPUI, i can create a Groovy script where i can define an arbitrary variable to the run context to retrieve at a later time.

```
context.previouslyUndefinedVariable = 3

def num = context.previouslyUndefinedVariable
```

What feature of Groovy allows previously undefined variables to be added to an object like this? I would like to learn more about it.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groovy has the ability to dynamically add methods to a class through metaprogramming.

To learn more, see:

- [What is Groovy's MetaClass used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340189/what-is-groovys-metaclass-used-for)
- [Groovy Goodness: Add Methods Dynamically to Classes with ExpandoMetaClass](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/11/groovy-goodness-add-methods-dynamically.html)
- [Runtime and compile-time metaprogramming](http://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is a bit of a poor explanation for how SoapUI is doing it.

In this case, `context` is always an instance of some SoapUI library java class (such as `WsdlTestRunContext`), and these are all implementations of `Map`. You can check `context.getClass()` and `assert context in Map`.

When you look up a property on a Map, Groovy uses the getAt and putAt methods. There are various syntaxes you can use. All of these are equivalent:

```
context.someUndef
context.'someUndef'
context[someUndef]
context['someUndef']
context.getAt('someUndef')
```

And

```
context.someUndef = 3
context.'someUndef' = 3
context[someUndef] = 3
context['someUndef'] = 3
context.putAt('someUndef', 3)
```

I like to use any of the above that include quote marks, so that Groovy-Eclipse doesn't flag it as a missing property.

It's also interesting that Groovy looks for a `getAt()` method before it checks for a `get` method being referred to as a property.

For example, consider evaluating `"foo".class`. The String instance doesn't have a property called `class` and it also doesn't have a method `getAt(String)`, so the next thing it tries is to look for a "get" method with that name, i.e. `getClass()`, which it finds, and we get our result: `String`.

But with a map, `['class':'bar'].class` refers to the method call `getAt('class')` first, which will be `'bar'`. If we want to know what type of Map it is, we have to be more specific and write in full: `['class':'bar'].getClass()` which will be `LinkedHashMap`.

We still have to specify `getClass()` even if that `Map` doesn't have a matching key, because  `['foo':'bar'].class` will still mean `['foo':'bar'].getAt('class')`, which will be `null`.